# Fastest way to record all DocIds and FileNames from dtSearch in SQL database

Tags: sql-server, dtsearch

I am using dtSearch on combination with a SQL database and would like to maintain a table that includes all DocIds and their related FileNames. From there, I will add a column with my foreign key to allow me to combine text and database searches.

I have code to simply return all the records in the index and add them one by one to the DB. This, however, takes FOREVER, and doesn't address the issue of how to simply append new records as they are added to the index. But just in case it helps:

```
MyDatabaseContext db = new StateScapeEntities();
IndexJob ij = new dtSearch.Engine.IndexJob();

ij.IndexPath = @"d:\myindex";

IndexInfo indexInfo = dtSearch.Engine.IndexJob.GetIndexInfo(@"d:\myindex");

bool jobDone =   ij.Execute();

SearchResults sr = new SearchResults();

uint n = indexInfo.DocCount;

for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
{
    sr.AddDoc(ij.IndexPath, i, null);
}

for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
{
    sr.GetNthDoc(i - 1);
        //IndexDocument is defined elsewhere
        IndexDocument id = new IndexDocument();
        id.DocId = sr.CurrentItem.DocId;
        id.FilePath = sr.CurrentItem.Filename;

        if (id.FilePath != null)
        {
            db.IndexDocuments.Add(id);
            db.SaveChanges();           
        }   
}
```

Comment: Where you able to find a solution to this? I've been researching the same exact problem. Also, have you found a workaround to the docId changing after the index has been updated?

Comment: No luck yet, Jason. I'll post something here if/when that changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I used part of user2172986's response, but combined it with some additional code to get the solution to my question. I did indeed have to set the *dtsKeepExistingDocIds* flag in my index update routine.
From there, I only wanted to add the newly created DocIds to my SQL database. For that, I used the following code:

```
string indexPath = @"d:\myindex"; 

        using (IndexJob ij = new dtSearch.Engine.IndexJob())
        {
            //make sure the updated index doesn't change DocIds
            ij.IndexingFlags = IndexingFlags.dtsIndexKeepExistingDocIds;
            ij.IndexPath = indexPath;
            ij.ActionAdd = true;
            ij.FoldersToIndex.Add( indexPath + "<+>");
            ij.IncludeFilters.Add( "*");
            bool jobDone = ij.Execute();
        }
        //create a DataTable to hold results
        DataTable newIndexDoc = MakeTempIndexDocTable(); //this is a custom method not included in this example; just creates a DataTable with the appropriate columns

        //connect to the DB;
        MyDataBase db = new MyDataBase(); //again, custom code not included - link to EntityFramework entity

        //get the last DocId in the DB?
        int lastDbDocId = db.IndexDocuments.OrderByDescending(i => i.DocId).FirstOrDefault().DocId;

        //get the last DocId in the Index
        IndexInfo indexInfo = dtSearch.Engine.IndexJob.GetIndexInfo(indexPath);

        uint latestIndexDocId = indexInfo.LastDocId;

        //create a searchFilter
        dtSearch.Engine.SearchFilter sf = new SearchFilter();

        int indexId = sf.AddIndex(indexPath);


        //only select new records (from one greater than the last DocId in the DB to the last DocId in the index itself
        sf.SelectItems(indexId, lastDbDocId + 1, int.Parse(latestIndexDocId.ToString()), true);

        using (SearchJob sj = new dtSearch.Engine.SearchJob())
        {
           sj.SetFilter(sf);
           //return every document in the specified range (using xfirstword)
           sj.Request = "xfirstword";
           // Specify the path to the index to search here
           sj.IndexesToSearch.Add(indexPath);


          //additional flags and limits redacted for clarity

           sj.Execute();

           // Store the error message in the status
           //redacted for clarity



           SearchResults results = sj.Results;
           int startIdx = 0;
           int endIdx = results.Count;
           if (startIdx==endIdx)
               return;


           for (int i = startIdx; i < endIdx; i++)
           {
               results.GetNthDoc(i);

               IndexDocument id = new IndexDocument();
               id.DocId = results.CurrentItem.DocId;
               id.FileName= results.CurrentItem.Filename;

               if (id.FileName!= null)
               {

                   DataRow row = newIndexDoc.NewRow();

                   row["DocId"] = id.DocId;
                   row["FileName"] = id.FileName;

                   newIndexDoc.Rows.Add(row);
               }


           }

           newIndexDoc.AcceptChanges();

           //SqlBulkCopy
           using (SqlConnection connection =
                  new SqlConnection(db.Database.Connection.ConnectionString))
           {
               connection.Open();

               using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection))
               {
                   bulkCopy.DestinationTableName =
                       "dbo.IndexDocument";

                   try
                   {
                       // Write from the source to the destination.
                       bulkCopy.WriteToServer(newIndexDoc);
                   }
                   catch (Exception ex)
                   {
                       Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                   }
               }
           }

           newIndexDoc.Clear();
           db.UpdateIndexDocument();
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

To keep the DocId in the index you must use the flag *dtsIndexKeepExistingDocIds* in the IndexJob

You can also look the dtSearch Text Retrieval Engine Programmer's Reference when the DocID is changed

- When a document is added to an index, it is assigned a DocId, and DocIds are always numbered sequentially.
- When a document is reindexed, the old DocId is cancelled and a new DocId is assigned.
- When an index is compressed, all DocIds in the index are renumbered to remove the cancelled DocIds unless the dtsIndexKeepExistingDocIds flag is set in IndexJob.
- When an index is merged into another index, DocIds in the target index are never changed. The documents merged into the target index will all be assigned new, sequentially-numbered DocIds, unless (a) the dtsIndexKeepExistingDocIds flag is set in IndexJob and (b) the indexes have non-overlapping ranges of doc ids.

Comment: So does that mean the DocIds change every time the index is updated?

Comment: No, not every time ! Please read my answer when the DocID will change.

Comment: I guess my confusion is the use of the word "reindexed" as opposed to "updated" - what is the difference?

Comment: If you have word document and make some changes, dtSearch will be regocnize the _update_ and _reindexed_ the content. You see it is the same.

Comment: Okay, so I can prevent the index from reissuing different DocIds. Now, how do I go about adding new DocIds to the database as efficiently as possible?

Answer (score 1):

To improve your speed you can search for the word "*xfirstword*" and get all documents in an index.

You can also look to the faq [How to retrieve all documents in an index](https://support.dtsearch.com/dts0207.htm)

Comment: This bit about using xfirstword is a relevant part of the ultimate solution

Answer (score 0):

Here is my new solution with AddDoc method from the SearchResults interface:

First get the StartingDocID and the LastDocID from the IndexInfo and walk the loop like this:

```
function GetFilename(paDocID: Integer): String;    
var
  lCOMSearchResults:       ISearchResults;
  lSearchResults_Count:    Integer;
begin
  if Assigned(prCOMServer) then
  begin
    lCOMSearchResults := prCOMServer.NewSearchResults as ISearchResults;
    lCOMSearchResults.AddDoc(GetIndexPath(prIndexContent), paDocID, 0);
    lSearchResults_Count := lCOMSearchResults.Count;

    if lSearchResults_Count = 1 then
    begin
      lCOMSearchResults.GetNthDoc(0);
      Result := lCOMSearchResults.DocDetailItem['_Filename'];
    end;
  end;
end
```